# Ruby Test::Unit's current test method name

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, methods, testunit

In Ruby's Test::Unit, how do I get the current test_ method's name? In MiniTest, this can be done by `self.__name__`, however, it doesn't work for the full version.

Comment: What are you going to do with it once you've got it? If you explain that, perhaps we could recommend an alternative way of writing the tests that wouldn't involve finding out the method name.

Comment: I have some annotations on the test method that I need to get by its method name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it!

The test name gets passed up the inheritance chain, so I just needed to capture it and save it locally for my reference.

```
def initialize(name = nil)
    @test_name = name
    super(name) unless name.nil?
end
```

Answer (score 5):

for completeness with Test::Unit 2.x it's `method_name` see http://git.io/7yngvg

```
def setup
  puts self.method_name # will output e.g. "test_check_username"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

yo can use **method**, like this example:

```
class MyTest
  def test_method_example
    __method__
  end
end
```

It includes a ":" char prefix to the method name

Comment: Yes, that's within the method. I was talking about outside of the method. Up the inheritance chain.